# Codec error when generating pdf via pdfkit

Tags: python, flask, character-encoding, pdf-generation

I am trying to generate pdf file from html template via pdfkit library. Everything works fine, expect the case when some special characters in local alphabet are used (e.g. "Ž" in this case). Then folowing error appears:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u017d' in
>   position 57: ordinal not in range(256)

Code:

```
if request.form['action'] == 'Print':
    config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=path_wkhtmltopdf)
    rendered = render_template('pdf.html')

    pdf = pdfkit.from_string(rendered, False, configuration=config)

    response = make_response(pdf)
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/pdf'

    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename='filename.pdf'

    return response
```

There is also defined charset in html template: `<meta charset="utf-8">`

Do you have any idea what is a root cause and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue fixed, I changed 'latin-1' to 'utf-8' in .\Python\Lib\http\server.py:

```
    def send_header(self, keyword, value):
    """Send a MIME header to the headers buffer."""
    if self.request_version != 'HTTP/0.9':
        if not hasattr(self, '_headers_buffer'):
            self._headers_buffer = []
        self._headers_buffer.append(
            ("%s: %s\r\n" % (keyword, value)).encode('utf-8', 'strict'))
```